# How can I cache streaming data on kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using `kafka` as streaming data layer. A nodejs application will consume data from `kafka` while a C++ application is producing streaming data and write to `kafka`. It works fine but I'd like to know whether I can use `kafka` to cache the streaming data and let `nodejs` to query.

I have a requirement to support basic `request - response` request for other clients. I will have to save the streaming data on `Redis` in my nodejs app and build an endpoint to allow clients to query from.

If `kafka` supports cache and query, I don't need to bring `Redis` in to this architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Streams KTable can act as a cache and supports key-value querying via its Interactive Streams feature. However, this API is only available via Java and the RPC layer must be manually setup (for example HTTP + JSON)